# Avatar Creator using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, download, png, avatar

I want to create something like an avatar creator which would consist in different layers from hairs to feet where the user can change each part individually and then save a .PNG or .JPG.

(Something like this one : http://southpark.cc.com/avatar )

I have found numerous things looking like this online but I havent found any working code.

Do you know somewhere where I could find a working template then change it, or do you have any advice on how to build it myself ? If I don't find the code I think I'll do it in javascript but I'm not quite sure on how to create a PNG from different elements in a web browser.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API

Comment: Working template ... not sure... but its fun assignment to work on. HTML Canvas api will help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm currently looking for some infos about HTML Canvas.
Also I found something I think might help me : http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/200/index.html